# A button position in relation to SVG- how to configure consistent postion

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a basic SVG on a page. The SVG scales with the size of the page which is what I want.

The SVG must be within an object tag as the real one I'm working with includes javascript and CSS within the file.

example.svg

```
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" viewBox="246 0 600 430.95">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
    </svg>
```

I have also added a drop-down button to the page. That too scales to the size of the page as a result of the `responsive-width` CSS class I've added.

However, I would like the button to always appear just below the SVG. I have managed to achieve this using `margin-top: 80%;`  when the screen is a specific size.

[image]

However, when I change the size of the browser (for example if I narrow it), the position of the button changes drastically, and sometimes appear over the top of the SVG.

[image]

My question is, how do I ensure the button always appear, for example 20px (or a given percentage) below the SVG?

Here is an example of how I'm currently trying to achieve this.

```css
body {
  background-color: #C1C1C1;
}

.responsive-width {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.tuner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-29%);
  margin-top: 5%;
  height: 65%;
}

.dropdownposition {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-top: 80%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<object type="image/svg+xml" data="example.svg" class="tuner"></object>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle responsive-width dropdownposition" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    My Dropdown
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @VXp , I'm confused as to why you edited my question so that the SVG was both within and object tag and embedded on the page? Now there are two main SVG when that was never the intention?

Comment: Also, the SVG needs to be in an object tag as I am using javascript and CSS within it

Comment: There was only one svg and now since you've edited it, none. You should create a snippet with the desired behavior in the first place, not just pasting the code here and there.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/zsguyw1e/6/`enter code here`

A quick and rough try ...
I think arranging the order in html can help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. This hasn't worked. The problem is, I want the svg to be centred. This is easy to achieve when I have it in an <object> element. When The svg is embedded in the page like it is in your answer it lands at the far left of the screen. Although this does seem to make it easier to position the dropdown below it, I can't find any easy way of making a embedded svg positioned centrally.